# tailwind flex classes not showing up

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to setup tailwind. When I use classnames of flex I expect the flex css property to show up in the element styles. All other element styles show up, but the flex related ones don't. This is in a new react app. Why is this happening? I setup tailwind using the tailwind cli with npx.

```
<div className="flex flex-row justify-between mx-auto bg-gray-200 shadow border p-8 m-10">
   <h1> Trending </h1>
   <h1> My Faves </h1>
</div>
```

my index.css file has the

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

[image]

Is flex not a part of tailwind or something?

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code, and i don't see error in there:

*my pakage.js file:*

```
{
  "name": "option-1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.5",
    "react": "16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "16.10.2",
    "tailwindcss": "3.0.24"
  }
}
```

*my taidwind.css file:*

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.scrollbar-none {
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
.scrollbar-none::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

*my index.js file:*

```
const Index = () => (
  <div className="flex flex-row justify-between mx-auto bg-gray-200 shadow border p-8 m-10">
    <h1> Trending </h1>
    <h1> My Faves </h1>
  </div>
);

export default Index;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your css file with this file:
[tailwind css codesandbox file](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-paper-eqng6v?file=/main.css)

I had got the same problem. Not all the classes were automatically come to the css file. I tried to solve by reinstalling but didn't work.